# Fetch dynamically a defined constant

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

According to Ruby `const_get`'s documentation, this method returns value for a constant.

So to reproduce the following behavior:

```
module A
  FOO = 42

  module B
    def self.call
      FOO
    end
  end
end

A::B.call # => 42
```

I wrote this code:

```
A = Module.new
A.const_set(:FOO, 42)
A.const_set(:B, Module.new do
  def self.call
    const_get(:FOO)
  end
end)
```

But when I call the method, I've got a `NameError` exception:

```
A::B.call # => exception
# NameError (uninitialized constant A::B::FOO)
# Did you mean?  A::FOO
```

It looks like `FOO` and `const_get(:FOO)` are not exactly the same.

Is there another way to find the `FOO` constant looking recursively in the parents modules?

**Edit:**

I also have this trouble with `const_get` doing directly:

```
module A
  FOO = 42

  module B
    def self.a_method
      const_get(:FOO)
    end
  end
end

A::B.a_method # => exception
# NameError (uninitialized constant A::B::FOO)
# Did you mean?  A::FOO
```

Comment: See this [article on constant lookup](https://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup). BTW, it's confusing, if not problematic, to use method names that are the same as the names of core methods (here `call`).

Comment: Defining `module B` inside of `module A` is actually different than defining `module A::B` straight-up. The wrapping implies a search scope that doesn't exist when you do it your other way.

Comment: I agree with @tadman's comment, and I added another example to be sure the code is ISO with the working `FOO` one. The only difference is that, I replaced `FOO` by `const_get(:FOO)`. And it is no longer working. So I think the trouble comes from `const_get` method IMO.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the method [Module::nesting](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-c-nesting) to better understand what is going on here.

```
module A
  FOO = 42
  module B
    puts "Module.nesting = #{Module.nesting}"
    def self.call
      FOO
    end
  end
end
```

displays

```
Module.nesting = [A::B, A]
```

This tells us that, when executing `A::B.call`, in searching for the value of `FOO`, Ruby first looks in module `A::B`, does not find it, then searches in module `A` where she does find it.

Your third code fragment also creates a nested module `A::B`:

```
module A
  FOO = 42
  module B
    puts "Module.nesting = #{Module.nesting}"
    def self.a_method
      const_get(:FOO)
    end
  end
end
```

displays

```
Module.nesting = [A::B, A]
```

`A::B.a_method` executes `A::B.const_get(:FOO)`. The doc for [Module#const_get](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-i-const_get) states, "Checks for a constant with the given name in mod." Therefore, if it fails to find the constant in the module that is its receiver it gives up without examining any modules within which the given module is nested.

Your second code fragment is similar to the third in that it fails to find the value of `FOO` because of the behaviour of `const_get`.

Comment: I undersand better with your explanation. But then, how (in pure meta-programming) I can create a module with a constant, and a sub-module, and get the constant through a class method? Is it not possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If `module A; FOO = 1; module B; def self.b; "FOO=#{FOO}"; end; end; end` then `A::B.b #=> "FOO=1"`. Is that what you mean? As I write my dog is pulling my pant leg, telling me it's time for a walk. I'll check in later.